# Entry Control: how to work with auto-generated MVVM methods

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui, maui-community-toolkit

Basic question, but I can't find the answer in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/entry) for the `Entry` control.

`CommunityToolkit.MvvV` comes with [these](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/generators/observableproperty) awesome auto-generated methods.  Here is one that I want to use with the `Entry` control:
`partial void OnNameChanged(string? value)`

Or:
`partial void OnNameChanging(string? value)`

The problem is that it works... too well.  When I set up either one of the above methods to work with an `Entry` control, the method is called as soon as a single character is typed into the control's user-input field, whereas the obvious behavior is that the method should trigger when the user hits `Enter` or clicks away.

In the docs there are ways to deal with this, but none of them appear to be `MvvM` (I very well could be misinterpreting or simply missing the fix).

Here is the World's Simplest Example of the error:

I have the ViewModel.  This is the entire class:

```
public partial class CheckboxMethodPageViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string name;

    partial void OnNameChanged(string value)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

I have the `Entry` control in the Xaml.  This is literally all of the code in the XAML:

```
<VerticalStackLayout>
     <Entry Placeholder="Enter a string value."
            Text={Binding Name}/>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

When I enter a character into the `Entry`'s text field it triggers the method `OnNameChanged( )` (same thing happens with `OnNameChanging( )`).  There doesn't appear to be a way to make it trigger after the user has hit `Enter`.

Is this just something that `MvvM` hasn't caught up to?

Comment: you can use EventToCommandBehavior to convert an event into an MVVM command

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the `OnNameChanged( )` in your viewmodel seems like the Entry's `TextChanged` event. And you said:

> the obvious behavior is that the method should trigger when the user hits Enter or clicks away.

They are two different behaviors. User hits Enter can trigger the entry's `Completed` event and user clicks away can trigger the entry's `UnFocused` event.

So you can check the official document about [EventToCommandBehavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior) and bind the Entry's `Completed` and `UnFocused` to the same command.

Comment: Hi Liyun!  I'm sorry I missed your comment.  How do I bind to an existing command?  Just make the event name `EventName=Completed` or something?  I actually need to do this using `CheckBox` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77189697/eventtocommandbehavior-breaking-on-checkbox-control)).  If you get a sec, can you give it a read?

Comment: Yes, just make the event name `EventName=Completed`.  And you need to make the parameter in the xaml have the same type as the parameter of the command in the viewmodel. @Bob