# EventToCommandBehavior breaking on CheckBox control

Tags: c#, mvvm, checkbox, maui

Using `EventToCommandBehaviors` ([here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/behaviors/event-to-command-behavior)) in a Maui MvvM project, I'm attempting to trigger a method when a `Checkbox` is selected, and I'm getting this exception:

> **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException**: “Exception has been thrown be the target of an invocation”.

I'm getting the same exact behavior on my "real" project and on a Sandbox solution to re-create the problem.  I also use `EventToCommandBehaviors` elsewhere in my project, so I know I can get it to work.

The exception is thrown when the code tries to run the XAML.

The problem may be in my Binding, but I don't see anything wrong with it, except that it's deep in a `CollectionView`.

I'm also using a `DataTrigger` on a `Frame` control that's bound to the `Checkbox`, but commenting it out doesn't effect the exception.

Here's the XAML (I'm sorry it's so wide):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Sandbox.ViewModel"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Sandbox.Model"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:CheckboxMethodPageViewModel"
             x:Class="Sandbox.View.CheckboxMethodPage"
             Title="CheckboxMethodPage">
            
      <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
            <Label Grid.Row="0" 
                   Margin="20,0,20,0" />

            <CollectionView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Things}">
                  <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                              <Grid Padding="5">
                                    <Frame Style="{StaticResource CardView}">
                                          <HorizontalStackLayout>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Name}"/>

                                                <CheckBox>
                                                      <CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                                            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChangedCommand"
                                                                                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:CheckboxMethodPageViewModel}}, Path=CheckChanged}"/>
                                                      </CheckBox.Behaviors>
                                                </CheckBox>
                                          </HorizontalStackLayout>

                                          <Frame.Triggers>
                                                <DataTrigger TargetType="Frame"
                                                             Binding="{Binding Source={x:Reference checkBox}, Path=IsChecked}"
                                                             Value="true">
                                                      <Setter Property="Background"
                                                              Value="#dee7ef" />
                                                      <Setter Property="BorderColor"
                                                              Value="#952e31" />
                                                </DataTrigger>
                                          </Frame.Triggers>
                                    </Frame>
                              </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                  </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
      </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Here's the relevant code in the corresponding ViewModel:

```
    [RelayCommand]
    private void CheckChanged()
    {
        return;
    }
```

I've also attempted every variation that I could think of for both the `Checkbox` XAML code and the C# method, and I always get the same exception.

Here's an example:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox">
      <CheckBox.Behaviors>
            <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChanged"
                                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:CheckboxMethodPageViewModel}}, Path=CheckChangedCommand}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
      </CheckBox.Behaviors>
</CheckBox>
```

```
    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task CheckChanged(ThingamaBob thingamajig)
    {
        return;
    }
```

I use `EventToCommandBehavior` elsewhere in this project, so I know I can get it to work.

I'm more than open for workaround suggestions.  I originally attempted to use `CommunityToolkit.MVVM` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77183131/entry-control-how-to-work-with-auto-generated-mvvm-methods)), but I couldn't get that to work, either.

=========================================================

### Still doesn't work, but I may be closer

I think that if there is already an Event for the control that you're trying to create a method for, you have to use that.  Also, there's weirdness when it comes to `EventToCommandBehavior` and `CheckBox`.

In any case, I got the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74319997/eventtocommandbehavior-throws-invalidoperationexception-in-maui-for-checkbox).

I don't know exactly how it works, but here is my `EventToCommandBehavior` command for `CheckBox` when it's inside of a `CollectionView`:

Name your contant page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
  xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
  ...  
  x:Name="this">
```

Here's the `CheckBox` control.  Note that the event that I'm using is `CheckedChange`, but you can name your actual method whatever.  `AddToCase` is a bool that's a property of the model object that I'm using in the `CollectionView`:

```
<CheckBox.Behaviors>
      <toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior  Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, 
                                                         Path=BindingContext.AddToListCommand}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding AddToCase}" 
                                       EventName="CheckedChanged" />
</CheckBox.Behaviors>
```

And here's my method:

```
    [RelayCommand]
    public static void AddToList(bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            // do the thing
        }
        else
        {
             // do theother thing
        }
    }
```

The problem that I have is that I'm inside a collection view and need to pass a parameter as well as the bool.  So, yeah.

Comment: What is the InnerException?  Have you tried doing this in a simple layout without a CollectionView?

Comment: Man, I don't know how to deal with exceptions in Maui.  When I hit "Show Call Stack", it always gives me the same thing.  Starts like this:
  0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception C#

Comment: So I can't get useful information from the Exceptions.

Comment: As for taking the it out of the CollectionView... I'm actually doing that now.

Comment: It's just a shot in the blue as they say, but I assume the event name (at least in the first XAML block) is likely a typo and the trailing "Command" should be removed, like: `<toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChangedCommand"` *=>* `<toolkit:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChanged"`

Comment: @lidqy I appreciate it, but... yeah, the "Command" thing is a typo (I always try every variation of everything, and sometimes this leads to typos).

Comment: @Bob okay. Next try: Do you know if the command is invoked at all, before the exception flies?
And is the DataContext of that checkbox of the expected argument type `ThingamaBob`?

Comment: I said that I use `EventToCommandBehavior` elsewhere in the project, but I only have it in the project as a child of `ContentPage`, where it works.  It seems I get the exception in everything but that.

Comment: @lidqy when I step through I never get to the command.  It breaks upon going to the Xaml.  The object that I passed through to the command in that second example was in reference to the example above, where I included `CommandParameter={Binding .}`.  If the code worked, it would've passed the object to the command.

Comment: I'd be fine working with a button instead of a checkbox, but I can't get the `DataTrigger` to work with the button.  If you look towards the bottom of the XAML, you'll see that when the `CheckBox` is checked it changes some properties of a `Frame` control.  IF I could get that to work with a button I'd be fine.

Comment: @Jason I take that back.  When I take everything out of the `CollectionView` it works.  The problem is with my Binding.

Comment: neither of the examples you posted have a `Path` that actually matches the name of the VM command

Comment: Assuming collection 'Things' is a generic IEnumerable<T> like List<T> or ObservableCollection<T>, the command parameter will be a T at runtime and the command execute callback must take a T. So in your case Things must be some IEnumerable of "ThingamaBob "

Comment: I'm not passing the parameter at all.  I was just seeing if I could.

Comment: @Jason ah, that's a typo.  Sorry.  I'll fix it.  The actual code doesn't have that problem (I went so far to the right that my formatting was all messed up, and I had to edit it).

Comment: Can you update your question, Please so i don't look at the wrong source code and answer incorrectly

Comment: "I think that if there is already an Event for the control that you're trying to create a method for, you have to use that" - why would you think otherwise?  The whole point of `EventToCommand` is to take an **existing event** and convert it to a `Command`

Answer (score -1):

You get this exception because the command parameter is not bool in the xaml. When you used the eventtocommand behavior, you need also pass the correct parameter.

The CheckedChanged event's parametor is CheckedChangedEventArgs in the code behind. When you want to bind the command in the viewmodel, you can custom the EventArgsContervor:

```
    public class CheckedChangedArgsConvertor : BaseConverterOneWay<CheckedChangedEventArgs?, bool>
    {
        public override bool DefaultConvertReturnValue { get; set; } = false;

        public override bool ConvertFrom(CheckedChangedEventArgs value, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value.Value;
        }
    }
```

And then use it in the xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
     <local:CheckedChangedArgsConvertor x:Key="ArgsToInt"/>
 </ContentPage.Resources>
 <StackLayout x:Name="layout">
     <CheckBox >
         <CheckBox.Behaviors>
             <mct:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="CheckedChanged"
                       Command="{Binding AddToListCommand}" 
                       EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource ArgsToInt}"/>
         </CheckBox.Behaviors>
     </CheckBox>
```

I have tested this and the command binding works. For moreintormation, you can refer to the official document about the [Binding value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/converters) and the source code about the [ItemTappedEventArgsConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/converters/item-tapped-eventargs-converter).

**Update:**
I get it working in the collectionview:

Refer to [this answer about command relative binding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63854494/17455524), `{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:CheckboxMethodPageViewModel}}, Path=CheckChanged` will not work.

And you can use the `CheckedChangedArgsConvertor` in my answer to pass the parameter. Or you can change the method in the viewmodel, such as:

```
[RelayCommand]
    public static void AddToList(CheckedChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        //args.Value is the current checked state of the checkbox
        if (args.Value)
        {
            // do the thing
        }
        else
        {
             // do theother thing
        }
    }
```

If you choose to change the method in the viewmodel, you don't have topass parameter.

Comment: Man, I'm sure it works on your machine, but I'm trying to access the command from the confines of  `CollectionView`, which makes Binding... difficult.  The `ContentPage.Resources` element ruins all of my bindings.  I've spent an hour or so trying to fix, with no love.

Comment: It DOES work when I take it out of `CollectionView`, so it certainly deserves the check (plus I'm sure I'll use this code elsewhere).

Comment: If you can get this working in the confines of `CollectionView` then I'll be amazed.

Comment: Please check the update part in my answer. @Bob

Comment: Did it work in the collectionview for you now? @Bob

Comment: Hi Liyun, I'm going to give this the old college try later this week.  I will certainly let you know.  Thank you VERY much -- I need to understand Convertors, so this will kill two birds using one stone.

Comment: Liyun, I dunno... your fix didn't work, but I'm confused as to what you would have me change.  I mean, I saw that CheckedChangedConverter class, but you didn't say how to use it in the Xaml (or in the ViewModel).  At least, that I can see.  Could you simplify the steps that are needed?

Comment: When I simply use the method `public static void AddToList(CheckedChangedEventArgs args)`, `args` is null, so it doesn't work.